# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object jump button in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get my player to jump when you press the button. I get NullReferenceException and can not find the solution to this could anyone help me with this? I have set the ground as tag "Ground", and made onClick on the button with the player as a reference.

The movement is working but not the jump button.

[image: Movement]

Comment: For future questions please remember to post code as next not as a screenshot.

Comment: You have to set the rb in the Start() Method and further more you never call Jump (At least not in that Screenshot). Another thing you should do is using a autoformater so your code looks more clean. this helps you and others to read it